# cache and memory handling on a java server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, memory-management, jboss

My java app is running out of memory after a while. So I am trying to find the most suitable way to manage the cache size. I do have the problem, that my cube is growing big if I don't clear  memory with LRU principle. How do you manage the cache size of you java vm?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I can set the parameters `CACHE_SIZE` and `FREE_MEMORY_PERCENTAGE`. But this doesnt seem to be the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I actually never solved to problem completely and I am not 100% satisfied with the current status, but anyways here is my current solution.

The system uses shared cache between sessions, so the memory which got allocated in the sessions gets cleared after session-end but the memory in the shared cache stays allocated.

A combination of the different parameters mentioned before + a quicker iteration of the garbage collector after each call of the memory operations works, at least, ok.